# Does ALICE use supervised or unsupervised machine learning

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am wondering what type of machine learning it uses and if someone could explain it to me. I have researched the different types and am unable to disngtuish what type it is due to my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

While it's hard to say for sure, the fact that they're using deep learning on GPUs - pointing towards neural networks [1] seems to suggest that they're using a combination of unsupervised and supervised learning. The latter for bootstrapping the bot, and the former to learn on the job.

[1] http://www.existor.com/ai-parallel

Answer (score 0):

call it weakly-supervised learning since we do not have exact labels but have intended document types. I dont know exaclty Cleverbot but state of the art takes large amount of documents and find models sequence relations of words by using Recurrent Neural Networks and LSTM in particular. Sometimes before it was Hidden Markov Models but now Deep Learning changed the game. If you search NLP with Recurrent Neural Network Google blows information.